# Does VMware have a tool for converting from Virtual Machines to Physical Disk Image (Reverse of Converter basically)

Tags: vmware

Does VMware have a tool for converting from Virtual Machines to Physical Disk Image (Reverse of Converter basically)?

Alternatively, is there a 3rd party tool that can do this from Vmware images?

Answer (score 5):

### Convert vmdk to physical disk image (Ubuntu/Debian)

If you have access to a Debian/Ubuntu system, first use `qemu-img` as explained [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Copying_an_image_to_a_physical_device) to create a raw image:

```
$ qemu-img convert -O raw diskimage.vmdk diskimage.raw
```

Then `dd` the disk image onto a hard drive (replace `/dev/sdb` with your disk device):

```
$ sudo dd if=diskimage.raw of=/dev/sdb
```

Or combined in a single step (replace `/dev/sdb` with your disk device):

```
$ sudo qemu-img convert -O raw diskimage.vmdk /dev/sdb
```

### Convert split disk to monolithic disk

If you have multiple vmdk files, combine them with command `vmware-vdiskmanager` (for more information on `vmware-vdiskmanager` see this [VMware article](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_vdiskmanager_run_ws.html) or the [Virtual Disk Manager User's Guide](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/VirtualDiskManager.pdf)):

- On OS X:

  ```
  $ /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager -r <filepath of original disk> -t 2 <filepath of new disk>
  ```
- On Linux:

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager -r <filepath of original disk> -t 2 <filepath of new disk>
  ```
- On Windows:

  ```
  > "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -r <filepath of original disk> -t 2 <filepath of new disk>
  ```

where:

`-r <filepath of original disk>` converts the specified virtual disk, creating a new virtual disk as a result. You must the name of the target virtual disk (`<filepath of new disk>`).

`-t 2` creates a preallocated virtual disk contained in a single virtual disk file.

Other method (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821916/vmware-fusion-how-do-i-combine-muliple-numbered-vmdk-files-into-a-flat-vmdk-fi)) is to select Virtual Machine>Settings>Hard Disk, uncheck "Split into 2GB files" and press Apply.